# Correct way to image on css shape?

Tags: html, css, centering, css-shapes

[Demo](http://beta.monikanormandphoto.com/)

HTML

```
<div id="headerCircle">
    <div class="logo">
    </div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
#headerCircle {
    width:460px;
    height:460px;
    background-color:#262626;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:-320px;
}

.logo {
    background:url(../images/logov2.png) no-repeat;
    width: 354px;
    height: 181px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    top:10px;

}
```

I'm trying to center the logo on the CSS shape I created. It seems to be just slightly off even though margin left and right are set to auto.

What I've tried
*Padding-left property
*Left property
*Un nested logo and used left and right property to manually position it

Comment: just FYI, not related to question, I noticed you are using full circle, but if you want a semicircle, then you can do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6bruzhjb/

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely implement that. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple solution

change your `.logo` `margin-left: auto;` to:

```
margin-left: 60px;
```

logo will be centered.

Comment: This is a better answer

Comment: Thanks that worked! Why did this work though? It doesn't make sense to me because it stays centered even if i make the width smaller. Its not a percentage either. Or maybe I need sleep haha.